# Saving file with an incremental number using vba MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I am developing a database program and part of the program is the ability fr the user to attach files. These files are then copied to a specified folder and renamed to reflect the ID of the table. However, my question is that I can achieve this but when the user attaches second file for the same ID it throws error for file already exists.

So could anyone put me in the right direction on how to achieve this i.e. If file exits then save second file an incremental number soon.

**some code to  help to understand what i am trying to achieve:**

```
Dim objFSO
Const OVER_WRITE_FILES = True
Set objFSO = Nothing
Dim FileLocation As String
Dim DestLocation As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim fileNameI As String
Dim iTemp As Integer

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

FileLocation = Me.lblTempLocation.Caption
DestLocation = "C:\Dev\"
fileName = [TestName].Value

'If the backup folder doesn't exist, create it.
If Not objFSO.FolderExists(DestLocation) Then
objFSO.CreateFolder (DestLocation)
End If

 'Copy the file as long as the file can be found

 If Not objFSO.FileExists(DestLocation & fileName & ".pdf") Then
     objFSO.CopyFile FileLocation, DestLocation & fileName & ".pdf", OVER_WRITE_FILES

     Else
         objFSO.CopyFile FileLocation, DestLocation & fileNameI & ".pdf", OVER_WRITE_FILES

        Do While (fileName) <> vbNullString
             fileNameI = fileName & Format$(iTemp, "_00")
         iTemp = iTemp + 1

         Loop

 End If
```

the above works fine first time but when the file exists and it goes through the loop it throughs a stack overflow error and stops the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use ID key of first table as foreign key relationship to a second tables 'FKeyID' (one to many table).  Create an 'AttachID' in the second table and set your VBA to rename the file based on the attachID allowing for multiple attaches per first table ID.

```
AttachID = second tables unique key
FKeyID = relation with ID from first table.
```

Comment: Thank for the reply, i did this and achieved the end results. it does give a unique file names [example: file_1_01.pdf and file_1_05.pdf for the same record if attached at separate occasion]. However, I was hoping for something like [file_1_01.pdf, file_1_02.pdf and so forth] for the same record. If that makes any sense. If its not something achievable then I'll have to do without it and have as you suggested.  Thanks for the response though.